# how to get the list of users accessing to particular tables or views

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the list of users accessing the sql server(database like tables/views),my users will access the views from excel sheet.

How to Track the user connecting to sql database and need to track on which table/view they are using!

I tried using sysprocesses but in these am getting the user list accessing to particular database but not getting the user accessing to particular table

Answer (score 0):

As long as the query is running, you can execute a system stored procedure:

```
sp_who3
```

which you can find under [db_name] - [Stored Procedures] - [dbo.sp_who3]. Unfortunately it doesn't log anywhere.

Easiest way is to modify it - add storing logs into own table. You can `INSERT` what it selects - Login, SQLStatement, StartTime.

Frankly speaking the logging table will grow huge very soon. Consider limiting logging to selected users!

Comment: am getting these Error;Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_who3'.

Comment: are you talking about SP_who2??

Comment: Thats fine but in addition to these i want to get the table which user is using with these am getting only the databsae which they are accessing,can u pls help me to get the table name as well