# How to view list of current users accessing a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to know if there's a way to view the list of current users or app that is currently accessing any specific tables in sql server 2012.

Comment: try **sp_Who**. It will fetch you the information about current users, sessions, and processes in an instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We can try with this query.

Query: Sql Server 2012

```
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables

    SQL Server 2000:

    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'
```

I hope this might help you.

-Bruce

Comment: it will not show who is accessing the tables currently

Comment: Would have a look at the below link, might be helpful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719992/how-to-get-the-list-of-users-accessing-to-particular-tables-or-views